# How to display Ads by Google differently?

Tags: google-adsense

I noticed some Ads by Google having different style than the original AdSense ads on few websites. Please have a look at the images below.

[image: Screenshot of one ad block]

[image: Screenshot of another ad block]

How can I have similar designed Google Ads on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of **AdSense Premium**. Premium members get a lot more freedom than ordinary AdSense users do, including having ad units with custom dimensions and ability to remove 'Ads by Google':

> **Flexible Adsense Ad Formats** - Premium clients can design their own Adsense Ad formats with custom font sizes, styles and color schemes. They can also create ad formats of custom dimensions that blend well with their existing site layouts.

(Source: http://labnol.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/privilege-of-being-adsense-premium.html)

To get such an account you need at least 20 million page views per month (or 5 million searches).

Answer (score 1):

**The AdSense interface lets you create custom styles. You can assign a style to each ad.**
This is done entirely on the AdSense interface and the ads will change style automatically on your website several minutes later.

There is limited flexibility but that is all Google will let you do. Styling the ad content themselves does not seem to work reliably and is not permitted. You can style the container of the ad though following Google's AdSense Guidelines.

Comment: In Google AdSense, there is only option to modify the colors and select from few fonts (http://d.pr/i/DGNd). There is no option to get ads like the above.

Comment: @Debiprasad - What *style* are you referring two exactly? You mean the layout of the ads? If so, that is generated based on the auction, so it changes according to what is deemed relevant.